Unary relationship with LeaderLine
I am working on an application to graphically represent Java classes in Class Diagram form.
PlainDraggable and LeaderLine made this task much easier.
However, I tried to create a unary / recursive relationship with LeaderLine (red line in the figure). The latter doesn't accept that an element to be start and end at the same time.
new LeaderLine(document.getElementById('OtherClass'), document.getElementById('OtherClass'));

I get the following error:

leader-line.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: start and end are required.
at it (leader-line.min.js:2:51907)
at ot.setOptions (leader-line.min.js:2:73051)
at new ot (leader-line.min.js:2:60892)
at mockup.html:212:16

Is there a technique or workaround to achieve this ?


What are PlainDraggable and LeaderLine?

They are Javascript frameworks. Please check links in the updated description.

The leader-line library doesn't support connecting an element to itself, but you can achieve a similar effect by using a "dummy" invisible element near the original element and connecting the original element to this dummy element.
Here’s a code snippet that demonstrates this:


new LeaderLine(
  document.getElementById('OtherClass'),
  document.getElementById('dummyElement'), {
    startSocket: 'right',
    endSocket: 'top',
    path: 'grid',
    startSocketGravity: 100,
    endSocketGravity: 50,
    color: 'red'
  },
);
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#OtherClass {
  width: 120px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

#dummyElement {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leader-line@1.0.7/leader-line.min.js"></script>
<div id="OtherClass">
  My Element
  <div id="dummyElement"></div>
</div>



By adjusting the position of the dummyElement and LeaderLine you can control the shape and position of the loop line.
